# Download Button Shiny App - How to fix error "Cannot Find Function"

Tags: r, shiny

I'm attempting to create a download button in my shiny app that downloads out an excel file with multiple tabs, once for each table in my shiny app. I believe I've put the code together correctly but I'm continuing to get the same error. `Warning: Error in table9: could not find function "table9" [No stack trace available]`
I think it has something to do with the fact that I'm referencing an observe event or even a reactive statement. Any ideas on how to get this working? Code is below:

```
rm(list=ls())
library(shiny)
library(RODBC)
library(DT)
library(openxlsx)
ui <- bootstrapPage(  tags$head(
  tags$style(HTML("
body{
    background-color: #FBFAFA;
}

h2 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font: Roboto;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 40px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #b00027;
    color: firebrick;
    height: 32px;
    width: 1140px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    perspective-origin: 570px 16px;
    transform-origin: 570px 16px;
    border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    margin: 5px 5px 20px;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}

.nav-tabs>li>a {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: darkgray;
    float: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
    perspective-origin: 569px 51.5px;
    background: white;
    border-top: 0px none rgb(34, 34, 34);
    border-right: 0px none rgb(34, 34, 34);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(217, 217, 217);
    border-left: 0px none rgb(34, 34, 34);
    outline: rgb(34, 34, 34) none 0px;
    margin: 5px 3px 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

table.dataTable thead th, table.dataTable thead td {
    padding: 10px 18px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
    font-size: medium;
    text-align: center;
}

table.dataTable tbody th, table.dataTable tbody td {
    padding: 8px 10px;
    font-size: medium;
    text-align: center;
}

.form-group.shiny-input-container {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 1%;
  margin: 0px;
}

caption {
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: firebrick;
    margin: 10px 5px 5px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: gray;
}

table.dataTable{
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 6px !important;
    margin-bottom: 6px !important;
    max-width: none !important;
    border-collapse: separate !important;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

.tab-content {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 2.5%;
    background: white;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: 50px;
}"
))
),
 titlePanel("Financial Planning Client Discovery Form"),
                                    
  
  tabsetPanel( id = "Main Panel", tabPanel("Client Selection",
  
  textInput(inputId = "First_Name",
              label = "First Name",
              value = "",
              width = NULL,
              placeholder = "Enter Client's First Name"),
  textInput(inputId = "Last_Name",
            label = "Last Name",
            value = "",
            width = NULL,
            placeholder = "Enter Client's Last Name"),
  textInput(inputId = "SSN",
            label = "Social Security Number",
            value = "",
            width = NULL,
            placeholder = "Enter Client's SSN (XXXXXXXXX)"),
  
  DT::dataTableOutput("MyTable")
  
), tabPanel("Client Discovery Form Information",downloadButton("downloadData","Download"), DT::dataTableOutput("CDFInfo"),DT::dataTableOutput("WealthSummary"), DT::dataTableOutput("Deposit"),DT::dataTableOutput("Investment"),DT::dataTableOutput("Loan"),
             DT::dataTableOutput("Other"))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  BDW <- odbcConnect("BDW", uid="", pwd="", believeNRows = FALSE)
  BOSCDB <- odbcConnect("BOSCDB", uid="", pwd="", believeNRows = FALSE)
  
  table1 <- reactive({sqlQuery(BDW,paste0("
                      SELECT DISTINCT a.PartyID, FullName as 'Name',TaxID as 'Social Security Number', AddressLine1+' '+City+' '+StateCode+' '+PostalCode as 'Address'
  FROM [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[Party]a
  LEFT JOIN [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[PartytoAddressRelationship]b ON b.PartyID = a.PartyID
  LEFT JOIN [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[Address]c ON c.AddressID = b.AddressID
  WHERE FullName like '",input$First_Name,"%'
  and FullName like '%",input$Last_Name,"'
  and TaxID like '%",input$SSN,"%'
  and a.ActiveRecordIndicator = 1
  and b.ActiveRecordIndicator = 1
  and c.ActiveRecordIndicator = 1"), as.is = TRUE)})
  
  
  output$MyTable = DT::renderDataTable({table1()}, caption = 'Client Selection',options = list(searching = FALSE, pageLength = 15,list(className = 'dt-left')), selection = 'single', rownames = FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input$MyTable_rows_selected, {
    row <- input$MyTable_rows_selected
    table2 <- reactive({sqlQuery(BDW,paste0("SELECT DISTINCT FullName as 'Name',DATEDIFF(hour,DateofBirthorIncorporation,GETDATE())/8766 as 'Age',CONVERT(varchar(10),DateofBirthorIncorporation, 120) as 'Date of Birth',TaxID as 'SSN',GenderCode as 'Gender', OccupationCodeDescription as 'Occupation',DigitalAddress as 'Email', AddressLine1+' '+City+' '+StateCode+' '+PostalCode as 'Address'
  FROM [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[Party]a
  LEFT JOIN [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[PartytoAddressRelationship]b ON b.PartyID = a.PartyID
  LEFT JOIN [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[Address]c ON c.AddressID = b.AddressID
  LEFT JOIN [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[PartytoDigitalAddressRelationship]d ON d.PartyID = a.PartyID
  LEFT JOIN [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[DigitalAddress]e ON e.DigitalAddressID = d.DigitalAddressID
  LEFT JOIN [BDW].[EnterpriseCustomer].[PartyOccupationCodes]g ON a.OccupationCode = g.OccupationCode
  WHERE
  a.PartyID =",table1()[row,"PartyID"],"
  and a.ActiveRecordIndicator = 1 and b.ActiveRecordIndicator = 1"), as.is = TRUE)})
  
  table8 <- reactive({sqlQuery(BOSCDB,paste0("SELECT DISTINCT TaxID, ltrim(rtrim(MinimumAnnualIncomeAmount))+' - '+ltrim(rtrim(MaximumAnnualIncomeAmount)) as 'Annual Income Band',ltrim(rtrim(MinimumNetWorthAmount))+' - '+ltrim(rtrim(MaximumNetWorthAmount)) as 'Net Worth Band',ltrim(rtrim(MinLiquidNetWorthAmt))+' - '+ltrim(rtrim(MaxLiquidNetWorthAmt)) as 'Liquid Net Worth Band'
  FROM [ExternalData_Stage].[dbo].[tblPrsCustomerAccount_G]a
  LEFT JOIN [ExternalData_Stage].[dbo].[tblPrsCustomerAccount_H]b ON b.AccountNumber = a.AccountNumber
  WHERE TaxID = '",table1()[row,"Social Security Number"],"'
  and a.DataDate = (SELECT MAX(DataDate) FROM [ExternalData_Stage].[dbo].[tblPrsCustomerAccount_G] WHERE TaxID = '",table1()[row,"Social Security Number"],"')"),as.is = TRUE)})
    
  table9 <- reactive({merge(table2(),table8(), by.x = "SSN", by.y = "TaxID", all.x = TRUE)})
    
  output$CDFInfo <- DT:: renderDataTable({table9()},options = list(dom='t'), caption = 'Client Information', rownames = FALSE)
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "Main Panel", selected = "Client Discovery Form Information")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$MyTable_rows_selected, {
    row <- input$MyTable_rows_selected
    table7 <- reactive({sqlQuery(BDW,paste0("SELECT DISTINCT FullName as 'Name',FORMAT(SUM(CASE WHEN ProductCategory = 'Deposit' THEN Value ELSE 0 END),'C', 'en-US') as 'Total Deposits Balance',FORMAT(SUM(CASE WHEN ProductCategory = 'Loan' THEN Value ELSE 0 END),'C','en-US') as 'Total Loans Balance',FORMAT(SUM(CASE WHEN ProductCategory = 'Investment' THEN Value ELSE 0 END),'C','en-us') as 'Total Investments Balance',FORMAT(SUM(CASE WHEN ProductCategory is null THEN Value ELSE 0 END),'C','en-US') as 'Total Other Balance'
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT PartyID, FinancialAccountID
  FROM [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[PartytoFinancialAccountRelationship]
  WHERE ActiveRecordIndicator = 1)a
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
  FROM [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[FinancialAccount]
  WHERE ActiveRecordIndicator = 1)b ON b.FinancialAccountID = a.FinancialAccountID
  LEFT JOIN [BDW].[EnterpriseCustomer].[FinancialAccountStatusCodes]c ON b.StatusCode = c.StatusCode
  LEFT JOIN [BDW].[EnterpriseCustomer].[FinancialAccountProductCodes]d ON  b.ProductCode = d.ProductCode AND b.SourceSystemCode = d.SourceSystemCode
  LEFT JOIN [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[FinancialAccountValueSnapshot]e ON b.FinancialAccountID = e.FinancialAccountID
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
  FROM [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[Party]
  WHERE ActiveRecordIndicator = 1)f ON a.PartyID = f.PartyID
  WHERE a.PartyID =",table1()[row,"PartyID"],"GROUP BY FullName"), as.is = TRUE)})
    output$WealthSummary <- DT:: renderDataTable({table7()},options = list(dom='t'), caption = 'Client Wealth Management Summary', rownames = FALSE)
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "Main Panel", selected = "Client Discovery Form Information")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$MyTable_rows_selected, {
    row <- input$MyTable_rows_selected
    table3 <- reactive({sqlQuery(BDW,paste0("SELECT DISTINCT FinancialAccountNumber as 'Account Number',FinancialAccountName as 'Account Name',OpenDate as 'Account Open Date', ProductType as 'Account Description', FORMAT(Value,'C','en-US') as 'Account Balance'
  FROM [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[PartytoFinancialAccountRelationship]a
  LEFT JOIN [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[FinancialAccount]b ON b.FinancialAccountID = a.FinancialAccountID
  LEFT JOIN [BDW].[EnterpriseCustomer].[FinancialAccountStatusCodes]c ON b.StatusCode = c.StatusCode
  LEFT JOIN [BDW].[EnterpriseCustomer].[FinancialAccountProductCodes]d ON b.ProductCode = d.ProductCode AND b.SourceSystemCode = d.SourceSystemCode
  LEFT JOIN [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[FinancialAccountValueSnapshot]e ON b.FinancialAccountID = e.FinancialAccountID
  LEFT JOIN [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[Party]f ON a.PartyID = f.PartyID
  WHERE a.PartyID =",table1()[row,"PartyID"],"AND ProductCategory = 'Deposit' AND StatusCategory = 'Open'
  AND b.ActiveRecordIndicator = 1"), as.is = TRUE)})
    output$Deposit <- DT:: renderDataTable({table3()},options = list(dom='t'), caption = 'Deposit Accounts', rownames = FALSE)
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "Main Panel", selected = "Client Discovery Form Information")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$MyTable_rows_selected, {
    row <- input$MyTable_rows_selected
    table4 <- reactive({sqlQuery(BDW,paste0("SELECT DISTINCT FinancialAccountNumber as 'Account Number',FinancialAccountName as 'Account Name',OpenDate as 'Account Open Date', ProductType as 'Account Description', FORMAT(Value,'C','en-US') as 'Account Balance'
  FROM [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[PartytoFinancialAccountRelationship]a
  LEFT JOIN [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[FinancialAccount]b ON b.FinancialAccountID = a.FinancialAccountID
  LEFT JOIN [BDW].[EnterpriseCustomer].[FinancialAccountStatusCodes]c ON b.StatusCode = c.StatusCode
  LEFT JOIN [BDW].[EnterpriseCustomer].[FinancialAccountProductCodes]d ON b.ProductCode = d.ProductCode AND b.SourceSystemCode = d.SourceSystemCode
  LEFT JOIN [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[FinancialAccountValueSnapshot]e ON b.FinancialAccountID = e.FinancialAccountID
  LEFT JOIN [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[Party]f ON a.PartyID = f.PartyID
  WHERE a.PartyID =",table1()[row,"PartyID"],"AND ProductCategory = 'Investment' AND StatusCategory = 'Open'
  AND b.ActiveRecordIndicator = 1"), as.is = TRUE)})
    output$Investment <- DT:: renderDataTable({table4()},options = list(dom='t'), caption = 'Investment Accounts', rownames = FALSE)
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "Main Panel", selected = "Client Discovery Form Information")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$MyTable_rows_selected, {
    row <- input$MyTable_rows_selected
    table5 <- reactive({sqlQuery(BDW,paste0("SELECT DISTINCT FinancialAccountNumber as 'Account Number',FinancialAccountName as 'Account Name',OpenDate as 'Account Open Date', ProductType as 'Account Description',ValueType as 'Balance Description', FORMAT(Value,'C','en-US') as 'Account Balance'
  FROM [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[PartytoFinancialAccountRelationship]a
  LEFT JOIN [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[FinancialAccount]b ON b.FinancialAccountID = a.FinancialAccountID
  LEFT JOIN [BDW].[EnterpriseCustomer].[FinancialAccountStatusCodes]c ON b.StatusCode = c.StatusCode
  LEFT JOIN [BDW].[EnterpriseCustomer].[FinancialAccountProductCodes]d ON b.ProductCode = d.ProductCode AND b.SourceSystemCode = d.SourceSystemCode
  LEFT JOIN [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[FinancialAccountValueSnapshot]e ON b.FinancialAccountID = e.FinancialAccountID
  LEFT JOIN [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[Party]f ON a.PartyID = f.PartyID
  WHERE a.PartyID =",table1()[row,"PartyID"],"AND ProductCategory = 'Loan' AND StatusCategory = 'Open'
  AND b.ActiveRecordIndicator = 1"), as.is = TRUE)})
    output$Loan <- DT:: renderDataTable({table5()},options = list(dom='t'), caption = 'Loan Accounts', rownames = FALSE)
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "Main Panel", selected = "Client Discovery Form Information")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$MyTable_rows_selected, {
    row <- input$MyTable_rows_selected
    table6 <- reactive({sqlQuery(BDW,paste0("SELECT DISTINCT FinancialAccountNumber as 'Account Number',FinancialAccountName as 'Account Name',OpenDate as 'Account Open Date', ProductType as 'Account Description', FORMAT(Value,'C','en-US') as 'Account Balance'
  FROM [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[PartytoFinancialAccountRelationship]a
  LEFT JOIN [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[FinancialAccount]b ON b.FinancialAccountID = a.FinancialAccountID
  LEFT JOIN [BDW].[EnterpriseCustomer].[FinancialAccountStatusCodes]c ON b.StatusCode = c.StatusCode
  LEFT JOIN [BDW].[EnterpriseCustomer].[FinancialAccountProductCodes]d ON b.ProductCode = d.ProductCode AND b.SourceSystemCode = d.SourceSystemCode
  LEFT JOIN [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[FinancialAccountValueSnapshot]e ON b.FinancialAccountID = e.FinancialAccountID
  LEFT JOIN [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[Party]f ON a.PartyID = f.PartyID
  WHERE a.PartyID =",table1()[row,"PartyID"],"AND ProductCategory is NULL AND StatusCategory = 'Open'
  AND b.ActiveRecordIndicator = 1"), as.is = TRUE)})
    output$Other <- DT:: renderDataTable({table6()},options = list(dom='t'), caption = 'Other Accounts', rownames = FALSE)
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "Main Panel", selected = "Client Discovery Form Information")
  })

  output$downloadData <-
    downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      "Financial_Planning_CDF_Data.xlsx"
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.xlsx(list("Client Information" = table9(),"Wealth Summary" = table7(),"Deposit Accounts" = table3(), "Investment Accounts" = table4(), "Loan Accounts" = table5(),"Other Accounts" = table6()), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  ) 
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You have posted a long and complex code.  If you want someone to help you please post a [MRE}(https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with some sample data.  Also, you are trying to download reactive objects created inside observers.  You should consider using `reactiveValues` object inside the observer, so that you can pass it to `downloadHandler`.

Comment: @YBS, where do I need to place the reactiveValues function?

Comment: I think you are quite close. All you have to do is place the reactive statements (```table9 <- reactive({...})```) outside the event handlers. This way, they are available anywhere in the server function and you can call them to generate the Excel file. At the moment, these functions are defined only within the respective event handlers, which is why you see the error.

Comment: Hey @Tom, I went ahead and placed them outside and I still got the same error. I simply just took the reactive({}) out of the "table <-" part and put in front of observeEvent(. That right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Tom, you can define reactive statements outside the event handlers or use reactiveValues objects as

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
   rv <- reactiveValues()
   
   observeEvent(input$MyTable_rows_selected, {
      row <- input$MyTable_rows_selected
      rv$table3 <- reactive({sqlQuery(BDW,...)})
   })

   output$downloadData <-
      downloadHandler(
         filename = function() {
            "Financial_Planning_CDF_Data.xlsx"
         },
         content = function(file) {
            write.xlsx(list("Deposit Accounts" = rv$table3...), file, row.names = FALSE)
         }
      )
}
```

Comment: what needs to go in the renderDataTable argument? I'm still getting the same error but I think it's because I'm using the wrong thing. Should it be "renderDataTable({rvtable3()}"?

Comment: Sorry, it should be `rv$table3`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be enough to restructure your code a bit. So for instance `table7` part, you would rewrite it like this to make it available throughout your server function (including the `downloadHandler`):

```r
table7 <- reactive({
    row <- input$MyTable_rows_selected
    sqlQuery(BDW,paste0("SELECT DISTINCT FullName as 'Name',FORMAT(SUM(CASE WHEN ProductCategory = 'Deposit' THEN Value ELSE 0 END),'C', 'en-US') as 'Total Deposits Balance',FORMAT(SUM(CASE WHEN ProductCategory = 'Loan' THEN Value ELSE 0 END),'C','en-US') as 'Total Loans Balance',FORMAT(SUM(CASE WHEN ProductCategory = 'Investment' THEN Value ELSE 0 END),'C','en-us') as 'Total Investments Balance',FORMAT(SUM(CASE WHEN ProductCategory is null THEN Value ELSE 0 END),'C','en-US') as 'Total Other Balance'
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT PartyID, FinancialAccountID
      FROM [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[PartytoFinancialAccountRelationship]
      WHERE ActiveRecordIndicator = 1)a
      LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
      FROM [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[FinancialAccount]
      WHERE ActiveRecordIndicator = 1)b ON b.FinancialAccountID = a.FinancialAccountID
      LEFT JOIN [BDW].[EnterpriseCustomer].[FinancialAccountStatusCodes]c ON b.StatusCode = c.StatusCode
      LEFT JOIN [BDW].[EnterpriseCustomer].[FinancialAccountProductCodes]d ON  b.ProductCode = d.ProductCode AND b.SourceSystemCode = d.SourceSystemCode
      LEFT JOIN [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[FinancialAccountValueSnapshot]e ON b.FinancialAccountID = e.FinancialAccountID
      LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
      FROM [EnterpriseCustomer].[dbo].[Party]
      WHERE ActiveRecordIndicator = 1)f ON a.PartyID = f.PartyID
      WHERE a.PartyID =",table1()[row,"PartyID"],"GROUP BY FullName"), as.is = TRUE)
})

observeEvent(input$MyTable_rows_selected, {
    output$WealthSummary <- DT:: renderDataTable(table7(),options = list(dom='t'), caption = 'Client Wealth Management Summary', rownames = FALSE)
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "Main Panel", selected = "Client Discovery Form Information")
  })
```